# Webcam disabled by AVG antivirus

Tags: c++, qt, opencv, antivirus

I am creating a program with Qt on Windows using OpenCV.
When I launch the program, sometimes, the webcam won't start. cam.open(0) returns 1 (open succesfull) but the frames are empty. I spent many hours on this and I finally pinpoint the problem to "AVG Protection". About 50% of the time I launched the program, I was receiving empty frames. With AVG uninstalled, it works 100% of the time.

I guess AVG was sometimes detecting my program as malicious or something. I tried adding the program in the AVG exceptions but it did not change anything.

Could I do something programatically to prevent this ?

Thank you very much,

Alex

Comment: Think about what you're asking -- if you could programmatically prevent an antivirus application from interfering with your software, why wouldn't malware take advantage of this "feature"?

Comment: Yes I understand. Since AVG only blocks the webcam sometimes and not always, I thought there might be something to do. Any other suggestions ? Like could I apply for any certificate which would let know some antivirus to let my program run ?

Answer (score 1):

The same problem here for us. Some days ago customers started to report that our application does not receive video data from the camera anymore.
There are no errors or any exceptions raised.
Yesterday, I have reproduced this issue on a laptop with AVG installed. From what I can find from logs, the camera can be found and started by the application, but it does not receive any frames from it. Namely, presentFrame() method from dscamerasession.cpp is not being called back anymore by Windows process, as it used to before.
There is a question at AVG support:
https://support.avg.com/answers#!/feedtype=SINGLE_QUESTION_DETAIL&dc=All&criteria=ALLQUESTIONS&id=906b0000000DlgTAAS

Their answer is:
Please follow the instructions to change the Firewall settings to check the status : Open AVG Zen -> Internet Security -> Click on Menu in the top right corner -> Settings -> Components -> Firewall -> Customize -> Network Profiles -> Change the networks from Public to Private (If it is in Private, change it to Public).
Then check whether you are able to access it without any issues